# Double requirement error when installing requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to install requirements for [package](https://github.com/Jcavazosg/ML_Facial_Rec) : I opened console and went to path with downloaded package & entered `pip install -r requirements.txt`, but error was given back:

> `ERROR: Double requirement given: numpy==1.17.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 36)) (already in numpy==1.16.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)), name='numpy')`

I was trying to enter `pip install -r requirements.txt --isolated` but it didn't helped me.

What should I do to aviod such an error?

Comment: The error is self explanatory, you have numpy package mentioned two times with different version. You need to remove one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't your fault,they included numpy *twice* in the requirements.txt file. You can try to delete one of the lines (36/2).
Or you can contact the devlopers to fix this bug.

Comment: is there a way to tell pip to take the last one (i.e. unintall first and use the last).  I can see a case where i would want a base requirements, but for some specific cases, would want to test a previous version of one of the libraries in the base.

Comment: It can be a little confusing.  Sometimes the lines are subtly different.  E.g., prompt_toolkit v prompt-toolkit (underscore v hyphen).